What is the correct maxmem parameter value in Python's hashlib.scrypt method?
I am trying to use Python's hashlib.scrypt to hash passwords. According to OWASP the recommended settings for scrypt are

... use scrypt with a minimum CPU/memory
cost parameter of (2^17), a minimum block size of 8 (1024 bytes),
and a parallelization parameter of 1.

Several places recommend the formula 128 * n * r as the value for maxmem.
However using this formula produces the following error:
from hashlib import scrypt
scrypt(b'password', salt=b'775186574b308535c9f0c1bedec71374', n=(2 ** 17), r=8, p=1, maxmem=(128 * (2 ** 17) * 8))
ValueError: [digital envelope routines: EVP_PBE_scrypt] memory limit exceeded

Through trial and error I have discovered that using 128 * n * r + (2 ** 10 + 2 ** 11) for maxmem is the exact value to resolve the error. What is the proper way to compute the value of maxmem?

Why not just not specify maxmem at all?

If I don't specify maxmem I get the error mentioned above.

You may find this bug report interesting (although the error message is different, maybe version related). According to this, 128*N*r*p is the memory requirement of scrypt and hashlib/OpenSSL needs an additional small portion (with your parameters, this is about 0.002% of the scrypt portion). I don't think the calculation of this small (implementation-dependent) fraction is specified anywhere. Instead, maxmem should simply be set a little higher across the board (at least for hashlib).

Incidentally, the maxmem default is 32 MiB (here), lower than required for your parameters: 128*(2^17)*8*1=128 MiB, which is why it must be specified explicitly.
